# mysql storedprocedure vs hsqldb storedprocedure

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data, hsqldb

I have the following stored procedure in mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_getJobs`()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM jobs_table;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and the following defined in hsqldb (for unit tests)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getJobs() READS SQL DATA
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
    BEGIN ATOMIC
       DECLARE result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM jobs_table FOR READ ONLY;
       OPEN result;
     END
```

Spring framework code that executes stored procedure

```
query = "Call sp_getJobs"; //This is used when MySql is database
query = "Call sp_getJobs()"; //This is used when HsqlDb is used in testing
getJdbcTemplate().query(query, rs -> {
        process(rs);
        return null;
      });

private void process(ResultSet rs) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The spring code that executes mysql works fine, however, when I execute the same code against hsqldb I get an empty result set (rs.next() returns false).

Note - The createdata.sql file that I use for testing, creates the jobs_table and populates it with 6 rows of data too. So the table should have data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the code below didnt work for only hsqldb stored procedure listed in question

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(query, rs -> {
        process(rs);
        return null;
      });

private void process(ResultSet rs) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

code below worked for all of them - mysql, sqlserver, informix & also hsqldb

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall =
      new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource())
        .withCatalogName(catalog)
        .withProcedureName(query);
```

where catalog is the package name. So, if your stored procedure is such as accounts.get_all_expired_accounts then catalog="accounts" & query="get_all_expired_accounts".

Answer (score 1):

The Spring code doesn't look right for HSQLDB procedures. It will probably work for a function that returns a table.

Change the procedure to FUNCTION and return a table containing the data.

Alternatively, use the procedure but after calling it, execute getMoreResults() prior to process(ResultSet rs) call.